# Crystal lang : in macro, best practice to add an argument to a Calling node

Tags: macros, crystal-lang

[Call#args](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/Crystal/Macros/Call.html#args%3AArrayLiteral-instance-method) is of type [ArrayLiteral](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/Crystal/Macros/ArrayLiteral.html) but ArrayLiteral doesn't have any method to insert element. So my problem is how to add an argument into calling elegantly.

I only know this stupid way:

```
macro method_missing(call)
    Delegator.{{call.name}}("a new parameter", {{call.args}}) {{call.block}}
end
```

But it's hard to deal with `#named_arg` and especially `#splat_index` (although it's member of `Block`, has the same question here)

Does some better approach exists or it'a todo feature for the compiler developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayLiteral` can actually be modified and it provides several methods for adding elements: `#<<`, `#[]=`, `#push`, `#unshift`.

There is no literal `#insert`, but it doesn't seem you're explicitly looking for that. It could probably be added to the macro interpreter. But it can also be implemented with `#select` and `#<<` for example.

Comment: My apologize, I just miss something :-)